# SQL query to a database

Tags: sql-server

I have an exercice that I've been trying to complete for hours, but still no luck.

Question:

List the name, address e number of borrowed book's for all the clients that have more than 5 books loaned.

The schematic is on the picture below and so far I have done this query, that is missing the number of books loaned

```
select 
    Name, Address  
from 
    borrower  
where 
    cardno in (select cardno 
               from book_loans 
               group by cardno 
               having count(cardno) in (select emprestimo.emprestimo 
                                        from
                                            (select COUNT(cardno) as emprestimo 
                                             from book_loans 
                                             group by cardno 
                                             having COUNT(cardno) >= 5) emprestimo));
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to use JOIN's?

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question?

Comment: Hi Robert thanks for the reply. I'm still learning SQL querying how can I do a join in my query?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Because of the word "exercise", the use of a picture to define schema rather than DDLm, and the idea that "learning" is not the same as asking others for a solution?

Comment: @SMor thanks for the info. I'm sure Joel now knows how to improve his question. But he did provide his shot at the solution. I don't even know what ddlm is, what about a beginner?
In my opinion the entrance level to ask a question on SO has become to high.

Comment: @SMor Tanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are learning, I'll give you pseudocode. You know about the having clause - that forms the basis for finding the clients. You apply that set of IDs (CardNo) by joining to borrower. Something like:

```
select <columns>
from (query to find cardnos > 5 books>) as cards
inner join Borrower as brw on ... 
order by ...;
```

And learn the next lesson well - a resultset is not guaranteed to be ordered without an order by clause.

Comment: Hello again Smor!!
After some studing into iner join and the pseudocode I came with the solution.
`code` SELECT name,
       address,
       emprestimo from
  (SELECT COUNT(cardno) AS emprestimo,cardno
   FROM book_loans
   GROUP BY cardno
   HAVING COUNT(cardno)>=5)emprestimo
INNER JOIN Borrower ON emprestimo.cardno = Borrower.cardno
ORDER BY name;`code` 
I appreciate all the time that you take to help me!!
Merry Christmas!!